# How to create single instance of application

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, single-instance

I am working on NFC application. when i application already opened and i read the information from NFC tag then activity open which registered Intent-Filter and this opens a new instance of application which has already opened.How can i close previous instance or open previous instance of application.

```
<activity android:name="com.tanzanite.realike.Fragments.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
         android:noHistory="false">

        <intent-filter>
             <action   android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>     
                       <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Please help me and Sorry for bad english..
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should use activity launch modes http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: but its not working.activity not clear to previous activity..i used already this..

Comment: @Shivamsaxena : if you already tried a suggestion from a comment/answer, but did not bother to mention it in the question, you're the only one to blame. plus, launchMode is exactly what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to receive NFC tag discovery events while your activity is already in the foreground, you should register with the NFC foreground dispatch system. See [Advanced NFC: Using the NFC Foreground Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450661/nfc-detection-either-start-activity-or-display-dialog).)

Answer (score -1):

Step: 1

Create a Class (for example BusinessModel), this class extends Application.
   This class load once when the application launch.
Step 2
In Android manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="package name.BusinessModel"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="package name.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```